# Neural network doesn't converge, weights aren't adjusted

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I have tried running this NN in order to solve a regression problem. However they weights aren't adjusted during the iterations, but stay constant. I've tried with different optimizers e.g. Adadelta and basic gradient descent.
Also I use batch normalization to preprocess the data.
Here is the code I use and also the logs, that show that the error on the validation set stays constant as well as the weights and biases:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import range

from load_trm_data import readDatasetFromHdf

datasetSize = 5000

train_dataset, train_labels, valid_dataset, valid_labels, test_dataset, test_labels  = readDatasetFromHdf(datasetSize)


print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)

def accuracy(predictions, labels):
    return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions) == np.argmax(labels))/predictions.shape[0])


def error_mean(predictions, labels):
    return np.mean(np.power(predictions - labels,2))


batch_size = 128

n_input_param = 14
n_layer_one = 30
n_output_layer = 1

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

 # Input data.
   tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, n_input_param))
   tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size))
   tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
   tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

   # Variables.
   weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input_param, n_layer_one]))
   biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_layer_one]))

   weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_layer_one, n_output_layer]))

   # Training computation.    
   mu = tf.Variable(0.0, name='mu')
   mu = tf.reduce_mean(tf_train_dataset, 0)
   variance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tf.sub(tf_train_dataset, mu), 2), 0) / batch_size
   epsilon = 0.001   

   batch_norm = tf.nn.batch_normalization(tf_train_dataset, mu, variance, None, None, epsilon)  


   logits = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(batch_norm, weights) + biases  )
   hidden = tf.matmul(logits, weights2) #+ biases2
   hidden = tf.Print(hidden, [hidden], "hidden: ")
   loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(tf.sub(hidden,tf_train_labels), 2)) 

   # Optimizer.
   #optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
   optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.01, 0.95, 1e-08, False) 
   opt_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[weights, weights2, biases])

   weights = tf.Print(weights, [weights], "Weights: ")
   weights2 = tf.Print(weights2, [weights2], "Weights2: ")
   biases = tf.Print(biases, [biases], "Biases: ")

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(hidden)
  valid_prediction = tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights)+biases), weights2)          
  test_prediction = tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights)+biases), weights2)  


  num_steps = 3001

  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
      tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
      print("Initialized")
  for step in range(num_steps):

      offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)

      batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
      batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size)].reshape(batch_size,)    

      feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels} _, l, predictions = session.run([opt_op, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)

      if (step % 500 == 0):
          print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
          print("Minibatch error: %f" % error_mean(predictions, batch_labels))
          print("Validation error: %f" % error_mean(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))

  print("Test mean error: %f" % error_mean(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Training set (5000, 14) (5000, 1)
Validation set (2500, 14) (2500, 1)
Test set (2500, 14) (2500, 1)
Initialized

Minibatch loss at step 0: 57.574135
Minibatch error: 20.750767
Validation error: 63221.228800

Minibatch loss at step 500: 67.077072
Minibatch error: 13.863234
Validation error: 63221.228800

Minibatch loss at step 1000: 41.973755
Minibatch error: 12.603945
Validation error: 63221.228800

Minibatch loss at step 1500: 57.691139
Minibatch error: 14.036787
Validation error: 63221.228800

Minibatch loss at step 2000: 55.477966
Minibatch error: 14.557659
Validation error: 63221.228800

Minibatch loss at step 2500: 86.001404
Minibatch error: 19.441383
Validation error: 63221.228800

Minibatch loss at step 3000: 92.167984
Minibatch error: 11.834186
Validation error: 63221.228800
Test mean error: 54048.582031

tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Biases: [0 0 0...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] hidden: [3.6555634 5.9512711 3.6907592...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Biases: [0 0 0...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights2: [-0.12304196 1.0204707 0.86253721...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] hidden: [-2.7658644 16.363554 -4.9159303...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Biases: [0 0 0...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights2: [-0.12304196 1.0204707 0.86253721...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] hidden: [-4.6260657 14.945541 -2.8992696...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights2: [-0.12304196 1.0204707 0.86253721...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Biases: [0 0 0...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] hidden: [4.5799894 15.350223 3.151691...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights2: [-0.12304196 1.0204707 0.86253721...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Biases: [0 0 0...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] hidden: [10.983672 13.306148 -3.630734...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Biases: [0 0 0...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights: [1.0648602 -0.6320048 1.2979335...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights2: [-0.12304196 1.0204707 0.86253721...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights: [1.0648602 -0.6320048 1.2979335...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Biases: [0 0 0...]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] Weights2: [-0.12304196 1.0204707 0.86253721...]

**EDIT:**
I tried to shrink the example code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from six.moves import range
from load_trm_data import readDatasetFromHdf

datasetSize = 5000
batch_size = 128

train_dataset, train_labels, valid_dataset, valid_labels, test_dataset, test_labels  = readDatasetFromHdf(datasetSize)

def error_mean(predictions, labels):
    return np.mean(np.power(predictions - labels,2))

n_input_param = 14
n_layer_one = 30
n_output_layer = 1

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

  # Input data.
  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, n_input_param))
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

  # Variables.
  weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input_param, n_layer_one]))
  biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_layer_one]))  
  weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_layer_one, n_output_layer]))

  #Batch normalization
  mu = tf.reduce_mean(tf_train_dataset, 0)
  variance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tf.sub(tf_train_dataset, mu), 2), 0) / batch_size    
  batch_norm = tf.nn.batch_normalization(tf_train_dataset, mu, variance, None, None, 0.001)  

  # Training computation
  logits = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(batch_norm, weights) + biases  )
  hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(logits, weights2) )
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(tf.sub(hidden,tf_train_labels), 2)) 

  # Optimizer
  optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.01, 0.95, 1e-08, False) 
  opt_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[weights, weights2, biases])

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
  train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(hidden)
  valid_prediction = tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights)+biases), weights2)          
  test_prediction = tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights)+biases), weights2)  

num_steps = 3001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

  for step in range(num_steps):

    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)

    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size)].reshape(batch_size,)    

    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run([opt_op, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

**EDIT:** Did I get the conceptual setup for a regression problem right (e.g. are the ReLu right)? Is it corrrect to use softmax at the output node?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to debug this large a script. Are you able to shrink the example down to something a bit smaller?

Comment: It's important to match transfer functions (sigmoid, relu, etc.) to cost functions (softmax, least squares, etc.) to avoid creating additional local optima. A softmax is meant to scale sigmoidal units to be interpreted as a multi-class probability. Try using least-squares with relu and see if you get better results?

Comment: You get train predictions and valid/test one in a different way. I'd bet a bag of diamonds against an empty nutshell that that is not the correct thing to do.